# XML Parse based on attribute ID

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm new to using XML with visual basic. What I'm trying to accomplish is loading data into textboxes based on the items node. I have done that with static addresses. What I want to do now however is be able to change it based upon the attribute of the **screen** node called **"ID"**.

For example if the attribute ID from the screen node = 36 I want aLabel.text to equal "Apples".
I'll accept an answer in C# too, I can do either or.

XML Example

```
<Screen attribute ="35">
    <A>Chrono Trigger</A>
</Screen>
<Screen attribute ="36">
    <A>Apples</A>
</Screen>
```

VB.Net Code

```
 doc.Load(files)
 Static NodeNumber As Integer = 0
 RichTextBox1.Text = (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen").Attributes.ItemOf("ID").InnerText)
 aLabel.Text = (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen/A").InnerText)
 bLabel.Text = (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen/B").InnerText)
 cLabel.Text = (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen/C").InnerText)
 dLabel.Text = (doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen/D").InnerText)
```

Comment: The function uses [xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx), try to search on how it works. It should look something like: Screen[@attribute='35']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to select the appropriate `Screen` element, like this

```
Dim screenNode as XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Main/Screen[@attribute = '35']")
```

The part with the square brackets (`[@attribute = '35']`) is a condition--kind of like an `If` statement.  The `@` symbol is used to specify that you are specifying the name of an attribute rather than an element.

Then you can read the sub-elements like this:

```
aLabel.Text = screenNode.SelectSingleNode("A").InnerText
bLabel.Text = screenNode.SelectSingleNode("B").InnerText
cLabel.Text = screenNode.SelectSingleNode("C").InnerText
dLabel.Text = screenNode.SelectSingleNode("D").InnerText
```

XPath is a very powerful query language, with many other features.  If you are going to be working with XML much, it would definitely recommend taking some time to at least learn its basics.

Comment: most of what I was missing was syntax. I knew of XPath, and its capability. Answered my question.